# Why does importing Module as a child give me error results although all of the routes are set up?

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading

Anyone tinkering with angular has been bitten (or torn to pieces) by the following issue, I'm trying to import "DashboardModule" as a child of AdminComponent:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { UserLayoutComponent } from "./layout/user-layout/user-layout.component";
import { AdminLayoutComponent } from './layout/admin-layout/admin-layout.component';


const routes: Routes =[
    {path:'',component:UserLayoutComponent},
    {path:'admin',component:AdminLayoutComponent,children:[
        {
            path:'dashboard',
            loadChildren: () => import('./views/admin/dashboard/dashboard.module')
            .then((m) => m.DashboardModule) },
    ]}
];





@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule{}
```

but the server complains about this :

```
Property 'then' does not exist on type '{ path: string; loadChildren: () => any; 
import(): any; './views/admin/dashboard/dashboard.module...'.

ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a 
local (non-exported) symbol 'routes'. Consider exporting the symbol (position 7:7 in the 
original .ts file), resolving symbol AppRoutingModule in 
/home/fares/Documents/MEAN/UniProject/src/app/app-routing.module.ts
```

Dashboard-Routing.Module is already imported by dashboard.module
and the dashboard-routing.module setting up perfectly:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'',component:DashboardComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

**do you have Any Idea Developers?**

Comment: you can try exporting the `DashboardRoutingModule` in the `DashboardModule` like this:
`exports: [DashboardRoutingModule]`

Comment: Are you using SSR..?

Comment: @MikeOne No, I'm not using SSR" Angular Universal", I use a normal Angular application execution